# Debug multi-tenant Next.js application in WebStorm or IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, debugging, intellij-idea, next.js, webstorm

I was trying to debug multi-tenant Next.js application in IntelliJ although there are multiple options in Edit Configuration (Debugging)

- Node.js
- NPM
- Attach to Node.js/Chrome
- JavaScript Debugger

First of all there is confusion on which one to use for what purpose. I tried all for a multi tenant Next.js application with following structure, however nothing from above worked:

```text
src/
|-- app/
|   |-- app1/
|   |   |-- main.ts      // Entry point for App1
|   |   |-- app1.module.ts // App1-specific module
|   |   |-- app1.controller.ts // App1-specific controllers
|   |   |-- app1.service.ts  // App1-specific services
|   |-- app2/
|   |   |-- main.ts      // Entry point for App2
|   |   |-- app2.module.ts // App2-specific module
|   |   |-- app2.controller.ts // App2-specific controllers
|   |   |-- app2.service.ts  // App2-specific services
|-- shared/
|-- app.module.ts
```

Can someone help me with same.

Comment: Normally the "Javascipt Debug" run configuration has to be used for debugging client-side code that is run in browser. "NPM" or "Node.js"- for server-side code. You can start the  script that you use to start your app in dev mode in debugger and then debug the "Javascipt Debug" configuration with your server URL

Comment: @lena as told above that method is working for normal nodejs or react code , however for multitenant nextjs applications its unable to pick the breakpoints